# How can I search the full contents of Angular's $templateCache with my factory service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I want to be able to search against all the templates I have loaded in the $templateCache. So far, I can only do one at a time with

```
$templateCache.get('testArticles/articles/article01.html')
```

but I want to search more than just that one article. I have tried

```
$templateCache.get('testArticles/**/*.html')
```

but that didn't work.

Is there a different .get attribute I can use to retrieve all the templates from the $templateCache and plug them into a variable?

Here is the full service I have so far:

```
; (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('searchService', searchService);

    searchService.$inject = ['$templateCache'];

    function searchService($templateCache) {
        var searchTerm = 'Test';


        return {
            getAllTemplates: getAllTemplates
        };

        function getAllTemplates() {
            var template = $templateCache.get('testArticles/articles/article01.html');
            console.log(template);

            var foundMatch = template.match(searchTerm);

            console.log(foundMatch);

        };


    };

})();
```

Comment: Why do you need all of them together?

Comment: I am creating a help file. Each template contains an article on how to do something in the application. When they search, I need to search across all articles in order to help them find what they are looking for.

Comment: But you need to know in which article you found it. I would suggest to store the articles names in an array, put the templates using that names, and then use the array for getting each template and so the match. You can store the key of the template where the search string is and do whatever you need.